# I can't insert null variable through bteq import data

Tags: unix, teradata

i tried to import data into teradata through a bteq import data, but i can't because i have this problem:

> *** Failure 2621 Bad character in format or data of LT_CDG_UNICO.NRO_VUELO_
>    REF.
>                   Statement# 1, Info =0 
>    *** Warning: Out of data.

This is i tried to import:

> LA;100;null;null;2016-01-01;2050-01-01

I create this bteq for import this:

```
bteq << CARGA_CDG_UNICO > ${FILE_LOG} 2> ERROR_${FCH_HRA}.LOG
.LOGON ${SERVER}/${USER},${PASS};
.IMPORT VARTEXT ';' FILE='${FILE2}';
.REPEAT *

 USING CDG_OPE(VARCHAR(20)), NRO_VLO(VARCHAR(20)), CDG_OPE_REF(VARCHAR(20)),NRO_VLO_REF(VARCHAR(20)), FCH_INI(VARCHAR(20)), FCH_FIN(VARCHAR(20))
 INSERT INTO ${DBTB}  (CDG_OPERADOR,NRO_VUELO,CDG_OPERADOR_REF,NRO_VUELO_REF,FCH_INI_VIGENCIA,FCH_FIN_ VIGENCIA) values  (:CDG_OPE,:NRO_VLO,:CDG_OPE_REF,:NRO_VLO_REF,:FCH_INI,:FCH_FIN);

.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;
.LOGOFF;
.QUIT 0;

 CARGA_CDG_UNICO
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `null` in your input file is treated as an actual value and your target is probably a numeric column, thus converting the string `null` fails.

You need to apply `NULLIF`, e.g.

```
NULLIF(CDG_OPERADOR_REF, 'null')
```